# How to put dropbox inside Iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have dropbox:

```
<div id='jqxDropDownList'></div>
```

and js:

```
  var source = [
      "Affogato",
      "Americano",
      "Bicerin",
      "Breve",
      "Café Bombón",
      "Café au lait"];
  // Create a jqxDropDownList
  $("#jqxDropDownList").jqxDropDownList({
      source: source,
      selectedIndex: 3,
      theme: 'energyblue',
      checkboxes:true
});
```

And this Iframe:

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

Here if [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/CLB86/315/).

My question is how to put dropbox inside Iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to point your iframe to a src, so your code needs to be in another page, as it were:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lp0qgsjd/ contains `<iframe src="https://jsfiddle.net/CLB86/320/show"></iframe>` and http://jsfiddle.net/CLB86/320/ has your code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.css"/>
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<div id='jqxDropDownList'></div>
```

and js:

```
var source = [
  "Affogato",
  "Americano",
  "Bicerin",
  "Breve",
  "Café Bombón",
  "Café au lait"];
// Create a jqxDropDownList
$("#jqxDropDownList").jqxDropDownList({
  source: source,
  selectedIndex: 3,
  theme: 'energyblue',
  checkboxes:true
});
```